# Animated Film / OVA ID: SciFi, Space Opera?, Spaceship becomes trapped near Sun, crew commits suicide by exiting/opening the craft

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, anime

I believe the film or episode may have been a Japanese animation from the 70s or 80s. A memorable scene of the movie: A damaged spacecraft becomes trapped slowly moving closer to the Sun (or star). As the spaceship begins to heat up the crew decide rather than to face a slow agonizing death, to open the ship and jump out. This scene may have been a cut-away illustrating what other characters were describing after the fact. Thanks!

Comment: This sounds a little like the Moties bailing out of their light sail ship at the beginning of the Mote in God's Eye by Larry Niven.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mote_in_God%27s_Eye